# MySQL SELECT issue two different rows, same place

Tags: mysql

```
------------------------------
| member          | place    |
|-----------------|----------|
| 3               | 1        |
| 6               | 2        |
| s8d9fg8328d55   | 1        |
| 744             | 2        |
------------------------------
```

What I want is a query, that will pair 2 members with the same place. Lets say:

```
Example 1:
------------------
SELECT `place` FROM `table` WHERE `member`='3' AND `member`='s8d9fg8328d55'
------------------  
Expected output: `place` = 1

Example 2:
------------------
SELECT `place` FROM `table` WHERE `member`='4' AND `member`='s8d9fg8328d55'
------------------  
Expected output: no rows
```

Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't the output of the first query return `place = 1`?

Comment: You are right, fixed.